# How to vertically center using Responsive React grid system built with styled-components?

Tags: html, reactjs, css, flexbox, styled-components

I'm using [grid-styled](https://github.com/jxnblk/grid-styled) to make a layout.

I currently have the following:

[image]

How can I make the red/green items vertically centered in the blue container?

Here is my code, am I doing this correctly?

......

```
const Container = styled(Box)`
  max-width: 1100px;
  background: violet;
`;
Container.defaultProps = {
  mx: 'auto',
};
```

.....

```
  <Box style={{ backgroundColor: 'darkBlue', minHeight: 500 }}>
    <Container>
      <Flex wrap>
        <Box
          p={36}
          width={[1, 1 / 2]}
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
        >
          {content[0]}
        </Box>
        <Box
          p={36}
          width={[1, 1 / 2]}
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}
        >
          {content[1]}
        </Box>
      </Flex>
    </Container>
  </Box>
```

help appreciated.

Comment: fyi, I the blue box is to be fluid, while the inside is not to be fluid, which is what the Container is for.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass props to tell the Flex (flexbox) what you are trying to do.

`<Flex>` accepts the `flexDirection` `align` and `justify` props which will tell it how to align the children.

Try this:

`<Flex flexDirection="row" align="center" justify="center" wrap>`

Comment: appreciate the help but that had no effect... I think the issue is I'm setting the `minHeight: 500` but the Container is not at that height... Could it be that the Container needs to be set to take up the height of the surrounding Box?

Comment: If you create a JSfiddle or codepen out of it, then we can try to help more.

Comment: FYI, setting a minHeight: 500 to the `<Flex flexDirection="row" align="center" justify="center" wrap>` above, gets it to work, but that feels like anti-flexbox right?

Comment: sadly with these inline style libraries it's hard to make a jsfiddle